# How to allow Flask-Admin to accept JSON for record creation

Tags: python, json, flask, python-requests, flask-admin

I would like to know if it is possible to use `Flask-Admin` with the python `requests` library to create new records in the database from a script. An example would be as such:

```
import requests

new_userdata = {'username': 'testuser', 'confirmed_at': None, 'login_count': 0, 'last_login_at': None, 'active': False, 'password': 'password', 'current_login_ip': None, 'last_login_ip': None, 'current_login_at': None, 'email': 'test@test.com'}

url = "http://localhost:5000/admin/user/new/"

r = requests.post(url, data=new_userdata, headers={"content-type":"application/json")
```

I tried this already, and it *does* successfully create a new `user` record in the database, but all the fields in the record are `null`. Is there a configuration setting that needs to be changed to allow this sort of behavior? I wasn't able to find in the `Flask-Admin` documentation that discussed this kind of usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending form data, but you're also saying that the content type is JSON.  If you were actually sending JSON data, you would either need to call `json.dumps`, or you would pass `json=` instead of `data=`.  Just remove the header and send form data, as it's obviously sufficient to handle the data you're sending and Flask-Admin recognizes it.